# Elasticsearch: Reindex aliases (copy them)

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to create a new index and reindex document from first created index to the last one.

After having using ReIndex API I've been able to "copy" all documents to destination index.

Nevertheless, I'm really looking forward to knowing whether I'm able to "copy" aliases from first index to the last one.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you really want to copy aliases? isn't it straightforward task, that even could be done manually?